# Pad vectors in tf.keras for LSTM

Tags: keras, lstm, padding, tf.keras, word-embedding

Keras has a preprocessing util to [pad sequences](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences), but it assumes that the sequences are integer numbers.

My sequences are vectors (my own embeddings, I do not want to use Keras embeddings), is there any way in which I can pad them to use in a LSTM?

Sequences can be made equal in Python, but the padding methods in Keras provide additional metainformation for layers like LSTM to consider for [masking](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/masking_and_padding).

Comment: do you mean that you don't what to have trainable emb or you don't want to use emb layer at all? (u can use emb layer to load your pretrained weights setting trainable=False)

Comment: loading the pretrained weights is not easy, I would prefer to keep it out of the layers, but using the embedding layer could be an acceptable workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a possibility to pad an array of float of different length with zeros

to mask the zeros you can use the masking layer (otherwise remove it)

I initialize your embeddings in a list because numpy can't handle array of different lenght. in the example, I use 4 samples of different lengths. the relative embeddings are stored in this list list([1,300],[2,300],[3,300],[4,300])

```
# recreate your embed
emb = []
for i in range(1,5):
    emb.append(np.random.uniform(0,1, (i,300)))

# custom padding function
def pad(x, max_len):
    new_x = np.zeros((max_len,x.shape[-1]))
    new_x[:len(x),:] = x # post padding
    return new_x

# pad own embeddings
emb = np.stack(list(map(lambda x: pad(x, max_len=100), emb)))

emb_model = tf.keras.Sequential()
emb_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(100, 300)))
emb_model.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32))

emb_model(emb)
```

Comment: I do not have arrays of floats, I have arrays of vectors (vectors of floats), all vectors are 300 length, but each sentence has a different number of vectors. I need to pad the sentences. I do not want to use keras Embedding layer, I have my own embeddings already computed.

Comment: ok, can you provide some shapes numerical example? all the vectors are stored in the same array?

Comment: the shape is `[None, [10-100], 300]`, i.e. the 2nd dimension is not fixed, may range from 10 to 100, and is where I need to do the padding. You can see it as: `[batch_size, sentence_length, embedding_size]`. Is this kind of example helpful? Is there anything else that could be helpful?

Comment: @Trylks I edited, hoping that this example suits more to your case, let me know

Comment: @Trylks let me know

Comment: I cannot check the code now, it seems good. My current solution does not use masking and also does the padding before feeding to the NN. In the weekend I will test your solution and compare the results with what I got. I was hoping that the padding (not the embedding) would be possible inside the NN (possibly in the GPU), but it seems not possible for the time being.

Comment: maybe you can customize the function inside a custom generator (if you have a lot of data) but this is most related to your case